# How to refer to an instance already saved in database?

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-data-jpa, h2

I'm trying to model in spring a relation between Movies and Actors. Here we have my two classes:

```
@Entity
public class Movie {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String genre;
    private String year;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<Actor> actors;

// getters and setters
```

```
@Entity
public class Actor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String age;

// getters and setters
```

I have defined a many to many unidirectional relation and it works okey but not in the following case. If I insert a new movie with new actors that are not already in database, it works well, all tables are correctly updated. But if I want to insert a new movie with an actor that is already saved, I do not want to save twice, I want that the relationship table refers to the actor that was already saved and in the Actor table no new actor is added.

The following JSON is the one that is send to the endpoint for creating a new movie:

```
{
  "actors": [
    {
      "age": "string",
      "dni": "string",
      "name": "string",
      "surname": "string"
    }
  ],
  "genre": "string",
  "title": "string",
  "year": "string"
}
```

So how can I insert a movie with an actor already in database so it is refered? Because if I insert a new one with exactly the same data I get saved this actor twice, and in the case that the identifier is repeated I get a Unique index or primary key violation.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an existing actor in the database, you must obtain it first and after add it in the list.

```
 @Autowired
 ActorRepository actorRepository;

 Optional<Actor> actorOptional = actorRepository.findById(id);
 if(actorOptional.isPresent()){
     movie.getActors().add(actorOptional.get());
 }else{
   // create new actor and add it to the list
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have Object identifier [ `@Id` ] on both the sides, you can use `session.saveOrUpdate`

From the Hibernate Docs:

> `saveOrUpdate()` does the following:
>
> - if the object is already persistent
>     in this session, do nothing
> - if another object associated with the
>     session has the same identifier, throw
>     an exception
> - **if the object has no
>     identifier property, `save()` it**
> - if the object's identifier has the value
>     assigned to a newly instantiated
>     object, `save()` it
> - if the object is
>     versioned by a `<version>` or
>     `<timestamp>`, and the version
>     property value is the same value
>     assigned to a newly instantiated
>     object, `save()` it
> - otherwise
>     `update()` the object